# Suppose that $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is continuous prove that the set $\{x : f(x) >a\} $ is open for all $a \in \mathbb R.$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Using continuity, and letting $\delta = r$, we have that $|| x - x_0 || < r$. This implies that $x \in B_r (x_0)$. Clearly $x$ is also in $A := \{x: f(x) > a\}$. Thus we have that $A$ is open. I am wondering if this is correct?

Comment: The given set is $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$. Since $(a,\infty)$ is open in $\mathbb R$ and $f$ is continuous, the result follows immediately.

Comment: @Javier "I am wondering if this is correct?" Well, at least I do not understand at all what you are doing there. You don't even declare the symbols you are using.

Comment: I'm sorry im using the fact that f is on tenuous on R^n. I typed this sort of in a rush

Comment: Do you know what you have to show? What is your definition for open?

Comment: @Javier we are missing details here. As others have noted, it is difficult to speak to the validity of your proof given that you have not defined your variables, and you have not given any context for your problem. Depending on your definition of "open" and "continuous" this problem has different answers, some of which are trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your definition of continuity (And also on your definition of open.) Using the so-called topological definition: Since $(a,\infty)$ is open, so is the preimage under a continuous function.

Alternatively, let $x \in \{x \mid f(x)>a\}$. Let $\epsilon=(f(x)-a)/2$. Then there exists some $\delta$ so that $f(\beta(x,\delta))\subseteq \beta(f(x),\epsilon)$. But then $x \in \beta(x,\delta) \subseteq \{x \mid f(x)>a\}$, hence the set is open.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is continuous.

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists\delta>0$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta \implies |f(x) -f(y)|<\epsilon$

Lets say that in English, for any epsilon ball (open set) in the image, there is a delta ball (open set) in the domain, and if x is inside the delta ball, f takes it to something inside the epsilon ball.

the image of set A = {$x:f(x) > a$} is open.  What is the definition of open?  For every point in the image, there exists a ball that contains that point, and everything inside the ball is in the set.
Every point in the image has an epsilon ball, every epsilon ball has a delta ball.
every point in A has a delta ball.
A is open.